# Fractional part summation and asymptotic expansion error

Tags: number-theory, summation, asymptotics, fractional-part

Let us consider the sum  $$\displaystyle T_K=\sum_{n \geq \sqrt{K}}^{{K}} \left\{ \sqrt {n^2-K} \right\}  $$ where $K$ is a positive integer and where $\{ \}$ indicates the fractional part. Its asymptotic expansion for $K \rightarrow \infty$ is

$$T_K=c  K + O(\sqrt{K})$$

where

$$c= \frac{  1+\gamma -\log(2) }{2}$$

and  $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant. A nice demostration of this expansion is given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1849251/limit-of-a-summation-involving-fractional-parts).

Now let us set $$A_K= c K- \frac{1}{2} \,\sqrt{K} -\frac{1}{8} \log(K)$$

where the last two terms of this quantity reflect the behaviour of the error term of the asymptotic expansion above. If we calculate the average value of the difference between $T_K$ and $A_K$ over all positive integers $K \leq N$, we have

$$\frac{1}{N} \sum_{K=1}^{N} (T_K- A_K) \approx 0.126....$$

for $N \rightarrow \infty \,\,$. I am interested in this constant term, for which there seems to be a rather slow convergence (the value above was calculated for $N=10^6\,$). In particular, I wonder whether this bias may have a closed-form expression. After some calculations, I found the quantity $$\gamma - \frac{1}{8} -  \frac{\log(2)}{2}+\frac{1}{48}=0.1264754...\,$$ but I would like to have a formal confirmation of this.

Comment: Try explaining in a few lines the asymptotic expansion..

Comment: Should it be $T_K=\frac{\gamma}{2} K + O(\sqrt{K})$ instead of $T_K=\frac{\gamma}{2} K + O(\sqrt{N})$?

Comment: What is $S_K$ here $\frac{1}{N} \sum_{K=1}^{N} (S_K- A_K) \approx 0.06....$? Should it be $T_K$ instead?

Comment: Typo corrected. Thanks.